# OpenCV colored open source alternatives to SIFT and SURF

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I would like to use OpenCV for my new Android Project. However I need completely Open Source Feature Detection Algorithms.

I already found out ORB which seems to be good.
I already tried it.
But I can't figure out whether it uses GrayScale Images in combination with the Android OpenCV SDK or if it uses the colored image internally.
If it uses GrayScale images, is there an alternative that uses Colored Images for Feature Detection, Extraction and Matching?

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, please go through the [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.org/documentation.html) before you venture onto *stackoverflow*. In most cases, you can find valuable information there and any problems arising there can be clarified here (*or atleast are intended to*).

Now to your question, [ORB](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html) uses grayscale images, however, there is an alternative descriptor for colored images called [Opponent ORB](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/features2d/DescriptorExtractor.html) in OpenCV. You don't specify which version you are using but I assume you are using a version from 2.4.

For this, the detector can be ORB or the others (which would detect on grayscale images) and descriptor of the detected keypoints can be for grayscale or colored (Opponent ORB and so on).

For matching the descriptors, you can use the same method as you are using for ORB.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Jeru Luke Thanks for the edit. Too much blood in my coffee stream ;)